# Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm wrong?

Tags: algorithm, graph

For the reference of this algorithm, please refer to,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

Post pseudo code below, and I think this line of code `v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.index)` should be `v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)`

Here is the original paper => http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~gilbert/cs240a/old/cs240aSpr2011/slides/TarjanDFS.pdf

```
 algorithm tarjan is
  input: graph G = (V, E)
  output: set of strongly connected components (sets of vertices)

  index := 0
  S := empty array
  for each v in V do
    if (v.index is undefined) then
      strongconnect(v)
    end if
  end for

  function strongconnect(v)
    // Set the depth index for v to the smallest unused index
    v.index := index
    v.lowlink := index
    index := index + 1
    S.push(v)
    v.onStack := true

    // Consider successors of v
    for each (v, w) in E do
      if (w.index is undefined) then
        // Successor w has not yet been visited; recurse on it
        strongconnect(w)
        v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)
      else if (w.onStack) then
        // Successor w is in stack S and hence in the current SCC
        // Note: The next line may look odd - but is correct.
        // It says w.index not w.lowlink; that is deliberate and from the original paper
        v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.index)
      end if
    end for

    // If v is a root node, pop the stack and generate an SCC
    if (v.lowlink = v.index) then
      start a new strongly connected component
      repeat
        w := S.pop()
        w.onStack := false
        add w to current strongly connected component
      while (w != v)
      output the current strongly connected component
    end if
  end function
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You do realise that Wikipedia is a community-edited site, and can thus sometimes be wrong? It also has it's own discussion section, which would be a much better place to discuss any potential mistakes, although [this issue seems to have been discussed there already](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm#Bug_in_second_subcase).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, the question is, this line of code `v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.index)` should be `v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)`, do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @Dukeling, looks like both versions are correct. BTW, how do you find this link? I did search on search engine and always land me to the official algorithm page on wikipedia, other than the discussion page on wikipedia.

Comment: @LinMa There's a "Talk" link at the top-left of the page (at least on PC).

Comment: @Dukeling, nice!

Comment: @Dukeling, BTW, if you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people in the future.

Comment: @LinMa Feel free to post such an answer yourself.